# Upload Folders to Fileshare with ASP.NET Core Website

Tags: asp.net-core, virtual-directory

I want my Uploads folder to reside on a fileshare.

Reason why I want this: Redundant frontend.

So instead of saving to:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wwwroot\Uploads

Uploads should be saved to:

> \\fileshare01\MyWebsite\Uploads

I am aware that [VirtualDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) exist. This works for reading from the fileshare but writing to the Uploads directory still writes to lokal drive.
So with VirtualDirectories I can access http://localhost/Uploads/myfile.png which is actually on the fileshare BUT new files are not written there!

Here (simplified) how I save files:

```
IFormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files;
var file = files.First();
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"Uploads\myfile.png", FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

When I try to save to the new network path as absolute path it seems I require higher permissions and end up with a 500.30 error. I guess because application pool user has too little permission which I think is a good thing.

**My Question:**

How is this problem solved as good-practice? Shouldn't everything work automagically when configuring a VirtualDirectory including writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I just got the 500.30 error because of an error in my appconfig.json. I didn't escape the backslashes in my base path.

I found this [blog post](https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/) saying

> There is no need to add a „virtual directory“ in IIS, this stuff is
>   deprecated

and explaining that this is the way it's done via Startup.cs Configure() method:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\server\path"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyPath"),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
});
```

Another configuration mystery of ASP.NET Core solved :)